# How would you correct the following sentences?

Tags: grammar, sentence

How would you correct the following sentences.( Formal)

Thank you in advance.

"I’d like to schedule a day-trip to you company in order to meet with you and  Ms. Jones for the interview possibly on Tuesday , Nov 28th, anytime after 2 PM or Monday, Dec 1st, between 10 AM to 11 AM."

Comment: "you company" --- "your company".

Comment: Thanks but other than is there anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you’ve indicated that this is a formal contact, I’ve taken more liberty at rewriting your text (versus simply cleaning it up) to reflect that.  Note the use of asterisk in lieu of a dash (to represent a bullet) as Stack Exchange is trying to interpret the dash as a marker for programming code.  Also note that I speak American English.  My version may be more direct than someone who speaks British English.

“I would like to schedule a day trip to visit your company and meet with you and Mrs. Jones.  Would either of these dates and times work for an interview?

- Tuesday, November 28th, anytime after 2 pm or
- Monday, December 1st, between 10 am and 11 am.”